# How to move a command to the next page if very little of its beginning is at the bottom of the current page?

Tags: page-breaking

I apologise if this is a duplicate but I can't seem to find something like this here. Perhaps because I don't know how to ask this correctly. I know that the theorem from AMS article does this.

I have this command,

```latex
% Question command
\gdef\@unitname{Question}  
\newcounter{UnitCounter}
\newcommand{\setunitname}[1]{\gdef\@unitname{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{UnitCounter}.\arabic{section}}
\newcommand{\question}[1][\arabic{UnitCounter}] {
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\value{UnitCounter}}}
  {\stepcounter{UnitCounter}}{}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\theHsection}{#1.\the\value{section}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1. \@unitname{}}
  \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}
  \noindent\textbf{\@unitname{} #1. }\ignorespaces
  }
```

Sometimes, when I start a question, e. g., `\question What is life?` and it is followed by a long answer, only the question appears at the end of the current page and the following text gets moved to the next page like this:

```
Page 1
.
.
.
Question 1. What is life?
~~~
Page 2
.
.
.
And, that's life!
```

In such cases, I'd like the question statement to be moved to the next page automatically, like this:

```
Page 1
.
.
.
[moved from here]
~~~
Page 2
Question 1. What is life?
.
.
.
And, that's life!
```

I saw a question here that I can no longer find that spoke of if only a certain percent of a command is at the end of a page then move its beginning to the next. One thing I did find was [Need Space](https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace). Is that it?

What is the best way to implement what I want on my question command?

Comment: Indeed, the [needspace package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace) and its user-level macros -- `\needspace`, `\Needspace`, and `\Needspace*` -- would appear to provide a promising approach.

Comment: A simple solution without packages is put the questions and  answers (Q&A) in some box, for instance a `\parbox` or a minipage, but the problem always will be the horrible spaces that remain in the first page when the Q&A does not fit.  This has not  solution except using floats,  but only if there are some plain text between the Q&A and it is fine have movable Q&A with respect this main text.

Comment: you can use lower level methods, but better would be to define your environment using `\newtheorem` or (as newtheorem does) to be a one item list with item `\item[\textbf{\@unitname{} #1. ]`  Then the basic latex list mechanism will take care of page breaks near the heading

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you elaborate on the `\item[\textbf{\@unitname{} #1. }]` approach? Do I need to wrap that within an environment? Otherwise I am getting, `ERROR: LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.`

Comment: yes almost all latex display environments are one itemistd: theorems center quote etc